# Center Dropdown Divs, Move Following Divs Down With Bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm starting out with Bootstrap and am running into two problems. First, I'm trying to get my hero-start-form div to be centered. I've tried "center-block", "inline-block", width with a "margin: 0 auto", and several other things that haven't worked. This is what I currently have (the "position: absolute" and "bottom: 0" were to put the .hero-start-form div at the bottom of the jumbotron):

```
.hero-start-form {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.hero-start-form .select-container {
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}
```

Second, the Bootstrap carousel code I've placed below the jumbotron is showing up on top of the jumbotron div instead of below it.

I tried this for the carousel:

```
#myCarousel {
    display: block;
    position: relative;
}
```

What am I missing?

Here's my JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/MichelleGlauser/8s7afkmv/5/

Comment: Try removing the float for your hero-start-form div like this: `float:none;` and then try centering it after.

Comment: I added "float: none;" and "margin: 0 auto;" to my hero-start-form class, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think your Fiddle was broken. The `.hero-start-form` was missing a closing `</div>` tag. I have updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uwkq05qg/1/). Are your problems still there?

Comment: Yes! That's why the carousel was riding up into the jumbotron. Now I still need to figure out the centering issue.

Comment: How is it suppose to be laid out? You want that form centered and below the jumbotron?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to have the form on the jumbotron but at the bottom (where it is now), but centered.